# Android: get ContntProvider results to Service and back to Activity

Tags: android, service, cursor, android-contentprovider

I have some activities that call a `Service` that uses a custom `ContentProvider` to insert/update/delete entries in a table. Now all these operations work but the activities do not receive any result from them. What I want now is to also implement the query operation but in this case I want the results to get back to the caller `Activity`. How do I do that?

The `ContentProvider` itself works as I was using it synchronously, so its code doesn't matter.
Here's the `Service`:

```
public class TaskService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = TaskService.class.getSimpleName();
    //Intent actions
    public static final String ACTION_INSERT = TAG + ".INSERT";
    public static final String ACTION_UPDATE = TAG + ".UPDATE";
    public static final String ACTION_DELETE = TAG + ".DELETE";
    public static final String ACTION_QUERY = TAG + ".QUERY";

    public static final String EXTRA_VALUES = TAG + ".ContentValues";

    public static void queryTasks(Context context, ContentValues values) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_QUERY);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUES, values);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public static void insertNewTask(Context context, ContentValues values) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUES, values);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public static void updateTask(Context context, Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_UPDATE);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUES, values);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public static void deleteTask(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.setData(uri);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public TaskService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (ACTION_INSERT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            ContentValues values = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_VALUES);
            performInsert(values);
        } else if (ACTION_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            ContentValues values = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_VALUES);
            performUpdate(intent.getData(), values);
        } else if (ACTION_DELETE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            performDelete(intent.getData());
        } else if (ACTION_QUERY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            performQuery(intent.getData());
        }
    }

    private void performInsert(ContentValues values) {
        if (getContentResolver().insert(DatabaseContract.CONTENT_URI, values) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inserted new task");
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error inserting new task");
        }
    }

    private void performQuery(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
         //TODO
    }

    private void performUpdate(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int count = getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "Updated " + count + " task items");
    }

    private void performDelete(Uri uri) {
        int count = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted "+count+" tasks");
    }
```

The `query()` method of course returns a `Cursor`. How do I send this `Cursor` back to the `Activity`?

Comment: use [loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) framework in your activity, most likely `CursorLoader`

Comment: Yes, that was an alternative, so I can't do this with a service?

Comment: you can use service to update/insert/delete but query should be done by `CursorLoader`, btw instead of `IntentService` do that by writing a custom `android.content.AsyncQueryHandler` - the docs say: *"A helper class to help make handling asynchronous ContentResolver queries easier."*

Comment: "I have some activities that call a Service that uses a custom ContentProvider to insert/update/delete entries in a table" -- um, why? Unless you are exposing this data to third-party apps, get rid of the `ContentProvider`. And you can get rid of the service, as this I/O should not take very long. Just use ordinary background threads, or `AsyncTask`, or RxJava, etc. (carefully).

Comment: yes, I know that, but it's an exercise, and has to be done with contentProvider

Comment: @CommonsWare `um, why?` i know that official docs say somewhere to avoid `ContentProvider` where the data is not exported outside but honestly i more believe in sources where optimized `ContentProvider.Transport` class is used when dealing with `ContentProvider` in the same process (so no slow `IBinder` transactions are used in that case)

Comment: @CommonsWare also when introducing loaders they added `CursorLoader` which works only with custom `ContentProvider` (but no some "`LocalSQLiteDBCursorLoader`") which simply means that a custom `CP` is a preferred way when implementing loaders

Comment: @pskink: IMHO, `ContentProvider` adds no value for in-process scenarios. You're stuck with this craptastic API (no exceptions, limited SQL, no transactions, auto-start even when not needed). And the `Loader` framework is of limited utility. To be honest, you are the first Android expert I have seen recommend in-process `ContentProvider` in **years**. Part of the reason for the Architecture Components is for Google to have an officially-supported alternative for what they have admitted were poor choices in advocating for in-process providers and the `Loader` framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare i agree there is a lot of new stuff like Room, Paging etc but it would be better if they clearly said: "ok we made bad decisions in the past (like CP / loaders / whatever) and you guys should avoid that stuff instead of our new great toys like ... ... "

Comment: @pskink: They admit this in conversations, and occasionally in a conference presentation. If you're looking for docs, Medium posts, or any other written form... I wouldn't expect that.

Comment: @CommonsWare indeed, nothing more nothing less